# Hiding a variable from other applications and classes

Tags: java, security, variables, reflection, hide

I am creating an application in java that requires a variable to be kept totally secret and not be accessible to anyone. I initially thought of using the 'private' access modifier, however that would still leave it vulnerable to reflection. I have no idea if maybe 'protected' can be accessed by reflection also and I am hoping someone can give me a way of disallowing other programs access to this variable at runtime!

Many thanks in advance,
Edward Brown

Comment: Use a **code obfuscator** too. Like a database stores passwords encrypted, you could do that when only verification is needed. Or you could use a Java KeyStore to store the value (maybe even more unsafe). Or you could get the value using native C. It depends on the point of usage. You could split the value's bits through several variables, and shove/transform them constantly.

Comment: "Requires" why? You need to explain your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection can see any variable no matter the access modifier.  If you store it in memory, it can be seen.

Why is it so important that it is totally secret?  If it's passwords, I recommend you read up on various ways to store passwords like these links:

SO question : [Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords)

this blog for encrypting passwords: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/secure-password-storage-donts-dos-and.html?ModPagespeed=noscript

Comment: No, I am not storing the password in plain text or anything like that. I just need to hide the encryption key at runtime.

Comment: By encryption key, I mean the symmetric cryptography key that I am using for the client and server to communicate to each other securely.